# Is there any way to get the height of a single page if you would print the page as a pdf?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pdf, material-ui

I'm trying to render a pdf from dynamic content with puppeteer and react. The layouting is done in material ui for react, so page-break-before:always is not an option because i need the grid layout which is flex and wont work with page-break-before. I need to get the height of one page, so the header of the next page doesn't overflow. If i calculate where the header should be with `pagewidth * Math.sqrt(2)`, it gives me the position value of where it actually is. But unfortunally when i go to print it it's overflowing by a few pixels and the error is getting bigger with each page. I have wondered how to fix this problem for the last 2 days. I've even tried resetting the position with a margin.

Here are some code snippets from my program which might maybe help.

```
let width = 800//document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().width
for (let pagewidth = width; pagewidth * Math.sqrt(2) < document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().height; pagewidth += width) {
  let pageBreakXPosition = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(2) * pagewidth)
  header.style.marginTop = pageBreakXPosition - header.getBoundingClientRect().top + "px"
}
```

this is just the "important" part of the code because all of the other code targets the elements' width or some other styles. My problem would really be fixed if i just knew the exact point where the page would break, but appareantly my calculation for pageBreakXPosition is wrong in some way.

attached is a picture of the overflow(if you look carefully you can see that the error is getting bigger):

[Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HLop.png)

[Page 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I44jk.png)

Comment: it will be a great help if you provide a stackblitz.

Comment: I would love to do so but unfortunately the app uses an api which has secret data and would need alot of reworking for me to make it public and otherwise the items wont be generated. Currently it is run by a google function.

Comment: In case it helps, you can use values like `21cm` for your CSS. Your code is based on 800 pixels, but the question is whether that's the actual width.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can set the height as per your requirement and that should work

Answer (score -1):

Use these:
`- document.height()

- document.body.scrollheight
- screen.height
- $(document).height()`